# "NestModule" , "NestMiddleware", "MiddlewareConsumer" has no exported member in types/@nestjs/common

Tags: middleware, nestjs

I am new to NestJs and tried implementing the middleware specified in NestJs documentation,
   https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

When NestMiddleware is imported i am getting the following error
" Module '"../../types/@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'NestMiddleware'". and similar errors while importing "NestModule" and "MiddlewareConsumer'.

Iam using nestJs version 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NestModule`, `MiddlewareConsumer`, and `NestMiddleware` are all imported from `@nestjs/common`. From your project root, that would be `<root>/node_modules/@nestjs/common/index`. If you are having trouble importing these sources, you may need to re-install your dependencies.